# Iterate through each checkboxes within SPFieldMultiChoice field in SP 2010 List newform.aspx and Validate

Tags: jquery, list-form, newform

I need to iterate through the all the check boxes within my `SPFieldMultiChoice` and check whether at least any one of the checkboxes are checked and if not checked, I need to `return false`.
 I have this field created in my `newform.aspx` in my `presaveaction` call. 
I tried with the below  code , but it didn't work:

```
  if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 0) 
  { 
    alert('Enter at least one checkbox.');
  } 
 else
  {
  }
```

Also below code also doesn't work.

```
   var count = $('#checkboxes input:checked').length;
```

I was trying to get the ID of the `SPFieldMultiChoice` field but,in the 
`F12 Dev Console`, am unable to see an ID for this control specifically.It's splitted into all the checkbox IDs, instead

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0) 
  { 
    alert('Enter at least one checkbox.');
  } 
 else
  {
  }
```

Comment: Assume this is working and in my presaveaction call I am getting the alert, so the functionality is achieved.As a  result, the end user checked one checkbox,so as per the logic,the  length must be 1.But for me, its showing 0 again! Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: I mean, I dont have a mechanism like, event handler, which tells to the js saying that I have checked  one checkbox and again I am clicking the save button-presaveaction- call.

Comment: Will this code fire again, after checking one check box and click on Save button, within my newform.aspx ?

Comment: It should refire upon clicking save again if it is inside your presave function yes

Comment: Exactly,That's the problem,its not refiring! , and I have written the code its inside the presaveaction call only.